# Tensorflow train.batch issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a dataset with 40 feature values for each item.
When I try to build a neural network using tensorflow( i am new to tensorflow), this line of the code, is raising an error.

```
for _ in range(n_batches):
            batches = tf.train.batch(input_list, batch_size=batch_size, enqueue_many=True, capacity=3)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Dimensions 1 and 40 are not compatible
```

**Edit:**
Input list is calculated by reading in the csv file which contains per item 40 values of feature data

```
with open('0.csv') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in spamreader:
    input_list.append(row)
    label.append([0,1])
```

As a sample, the csv file looks like this:

```
-303.49402956575165,122.79163957162679,-11.468865795473208,3.9811327671171512,15.337415109639783,-14.108867251441396,-6.2515380667284548,-2.5776250066394879,-11.151238822575237,0.80064220417869125,0.27982062264574636,-7.4540404067320498,1.1294160621043878,-0.19718258671031155,-4.8998361975682672,1.4096255573297396,-1.7156108756597495,-4.8841327368201828,1.1763404024624535,-1.4828051938843485,-4.4185680752011773,-0.23408318097388262,-1.4313336679963722,-2.350002729608391,-0.012519210688780043,-1.1211450861767087,-0.28546877503470003,1.0960108052925126,0.017672759764874924,2.2723680886768522,2.9337076178657373,0.80627947017775015,2.7373411634266391,2.6117883927402459,-0.17306332146016015,1.3495579191555498,1.2670127235105628,-1.2019882636572772,-0.19807357792275704,-0.11667725657652298
-324.95895982872742,129.16902362793437,-8.5782578426411202,4.8909691557978645,9.679460715739177,-21.516263281123845,-8.0416220828154454,-3.8078900557142812,-13.927945903788769,0.43952636061160394,-0.69085228125901854,-9.051802560349115,3.2384649283450346,0.51938767915475448,-7.6485369361057103,2.1827631457774346,-0.2975737631792475,-8.3214260824025619,-0.52396570369004059,1.1065859071072002,-2.3500738274356539,4.2447931265345034,7.879566058882304,6.0660506076869103,6.012983546020755,4.4649038449901903,2.1070954443797651,-0.26862183717859767,-1.495853591930427,0.52413729310912371,-0.85169785225746941,-3.675692955742599,-1.2819459279342635,-1.3243977571633176,-3.4214154132554886,-1.025319003875736,-1.5668864629221912,-4.3026170282653107,-1.9139061426068631,-0.64944140674848683
```

Comment: Could you show how `input_list` is calculated?

Comment: @GeertH, i hav updated the question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the input list to a single array first. You can supply a list of tensors/arrays to `tf.batch` but then every tensor will be split in batches of size `40`. Currently you are supplying a list of tensors that have batch size `1` and you are asking to create batches of size `40` *for each tensor these tensors*. As you cannot create 40 examples from 1 example, you get a dimension mismatch. So instead do something like:

```
import numpy as np
input_list = np.array(input_list)
labels = np.array(labels)
batch = tf.train.batch([input_list, labels], batch_size=batch_size, enqueue_many=True, capacity=3)
inputs = batch[0]
labels = batch[1]
```

You can then use inputs and labels to define your network and loss function. For instance (just an illustration, code not tested):

```
hidden = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 2)
loss = tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=hidden)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Also note that you need to call `tf.batch` only once, not in a loop. Everytime an operation is run that requires `inputs` or `labels`, `inputs` and `labels` will evaluate to a different batch.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  with tf.contrib.slim.queues.QueueRunners(sess):
    for i in range(n_batches):
      _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
      print("Loss for batch {}: {}".format(i, loss_value))
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. Update this line: `batches = tf.train.batch([input_list], batch_size=batch_size, enqueue_many=True, capacity=3)`

Comment: it enters into infinite loop, and prints nothing :(

Comment: My mistake (again). Sorry for being so sloppy. Could you try again please.

Comment: printing the batches works!!!! but m unable to use it to train the network

Comment: Printing the batches was just in illustration of the concept, you don't need to do that to actually train the network of course. I have updated my answer to illustrate the training process.

Comment: when i print, why is batch shape (10,38,40)?? 38 i get for number of samples. 40 i get for number of features for each sample, but 10??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `input_list` as a list of tensors. [`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch)

```
for _ in range(n_batches):
    batches = tf.train.batch([input_list], batch_size=batch_size, 
            enqueue_many=True, capacity=3)
```